IntelliJ IDEA console output incorrectly displays vertical tab characters (U+000B)
I'm experiencing an issue in IntelliJ IDEA where the console output incorrectly displays vertical tab characters (U+000B). When I run the following code:
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Line 1\u000BLine 2\u000BLine 3");
    }
}

The output on IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4 (Ultimate Edition) - Windows 10:
Line 1Line 2Line 3

I hope the result will be as follows
Line 1
      Line 2
            Line 3

Steps I've Tried:

I checked the Custom VM Option under Help->Edit Custom VM Options and add two line as below

-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8


I checked File Encoding UTF-8:



I checked the Edit Configuration


How can I adjust the console output to handle vertical tab characters correctly?

Check your font. Make sure you're using a monospace font.

I have changed to Monospaced Font under: File-> Setting -> Editor -> Font. It's not working for me

Some invisible control characters ( like vertical tab characters (U+000B)) is not supported by modern terminal or editor.

So, how can I test them?

Use ANSI escape sequence to control cursor position and text colors.
your vertical tab characters (U+000B) to ANSI Terminal is move cursor to next line.

(1) The guess is closest to what you want to do, the keywords are "ANSI escape code" and "ANSI terminal".

(2) Through ANSI escape code, you can control the cursor to go 1 line down and 5 characters to the left. Even please empty the entire screen


-(3) But this requires Terminal to support ANSI escape code.

(4) The old version of Windows 10 does not support ANSI escape code

(5) The Terminal in IDEA does not support ANSI escape code.

(6) You need Only when the Java program is executed in a normal Terminal environment can the ANSI escape code's cursor position control function take effect.


public static final String ESC = "\u001B[";
public static final String VT = ESC + "1B";
System.out.println("Line 1" + VT + "Line 2" + VT + "Line 3");


ANSICursorAndColorDemo.java
public class ANSICursorAndColorDemo {
    // ANSI escape sequence constants
    public static final String ESC = "\u001B[";
    public static final String VT = ESC + "1B";
    public static final String TEXT_COLOR_RED = "31m";
    public static final String TEXT_COLOR_GREEN = "32m";
    public static final String BACKGROUND_COLOR_YELLOW = "43m";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ANSI escape sequence: clear the entire screen
        System.out.print(ESC + "2J"); //"\033[2J" , "\u001B[2J"
        System.out.print(ESC + "H"); // Move the cursor to the upper left corner
        System.out.println("The screen is cleared!");

        // Move the cursor to row 12, column 12
        System.out.print(ESC + "12;12H");
        System.out.println("Move the cursor here: row 12 column 12");

        System.out.println("Line 1" + VT + "Line 2" + VT + "Line 3");

        // Set the text color to red
        System.out.print(ESC + TEXT_COLOR_RED);
        System.out.println("This is a red text");

        // Set the text color to green
        System.out.print(ESC + TEXT_COLOR_GREEN);
        System.out.println("This is a green text");

        // Set the background color to yellow and the foreground to blue
        System.out.print(ESC + "44;" + BACKGROUND_COLOR_YELLOW);
        System.out.println("Blue text, yellow background");

        // Reset Color
        System.out.print(ESC + "0m");
        System.out.println("Colors reset to default");

    }
}

Please note that you must run it in an environment that supports ANSI Terminal. CMD in older versions of Windows is not supported. PowerShell is not supported either. It is also not supported in the IDEA IDE environment.
Works on "newer versions" of Windows

Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise Evaluation
10.0.22621 N/A Build 22621

Windows CMD

Windows PowerShell

Will not work on older Windows:

Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation
10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763


Amazing. Thank you so much, sorry for the later reply.
